# pip installs version 0.0.0 of the package MarkupSafe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install MarkupSafe for python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 Running in Docker.
Running `pip3 install markupsafe==2.0.1` gives

```
Installing collected packages: markupsafe
Successfully installed markupsafe-0.0.0
```

I tried reinstalling, I tried `pip3 install` with `-U`, I still get version `0.0.0`.
Running `pip3 show -f markupsafe` gives

```
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: MarkupSafe
Version: 0.0.0
Summary: UNKNOWN
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
Installer: pip
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requires: 
Classifiers:
Files:
  MarkupSafe-0.0.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
  MarkupSafe-0.0.0.dist-info/INSTALLER
  MarkupSafe-0.0.0.dist-info/METADATA
  MarkupSafe-0.0.0.dist-info/RECORD
  MarkupSafe-0.0.0.dist-info/WHEEL
  MarkupSafe-0.0.0.dist-info/metadata.json
  MarkupSafe-0.0.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
  markupsafe/_speedups.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 21.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

so I can see the `__init__.py` and the rest of the `py` files are missing. This is the only package that causes a problem. Running `pip3 list -l` gives:

```
...
distro (1.5.0)
fasteners (0.16)
future (0.18.2)
idna (2.10)
Jinja2 (2.11.3)
MarkupSafe (0.0.0)        <----
node-semver (0.6.1)
packaging (20.9)
patch-ng (1.17.4)
pluginbase (1.0.1)
Pygments (2.9.0)
...
```

(without the `<----`)

Comment: Please don't install packages system-wide, you're going to have a bad time. Use virtualenvs. Then, upgrade your `pip` – and if you can, upgrade your Python. 3.5 is not supported anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`MarkupSafe` 1.1.1](https://pypi.org/project/MarkupSafe/1.1.1/) works with Python 2.7 and 3.4+ so install it with

```
pip3 install "markupsafe==1.1.1"
```

or

```
pip3 install "markupsafe<2.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

MarkupSafe (2.0.1) requires `Python >= 3.6`, so get a newer version of Python. [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/MarkupSafe/)